# trying to create a 'settings' component that can be used globally for configuration var

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a 'settings' component for my app that will store the global configuration settings. I have the component that is the container for making changes to them working, I have been able to create a default set of values, and now I'm trying to initial them with a service that will be called to fill in the runtime settings object. I am missing something fundamnetnal here on how this should be done I think. WHen I try and initialize the object in the service I get some error I don't know what to do with. Here is the service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { AppSettings } from '../shared/app-settings';
import { APPSETTINGS } from "../shared/defaultSettings";

@Injectable()
export class AppSettingsService {
  getSettings(): Observable<AppSettings> {
    let settings =  APPSETTINGS;
    return Observable.of<AppSettings>(settings);
  }
}
```

And here is where I try and use them in the settings-container component:

```
export class SettingsContainerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  defaultSettings: APPSETTINGS;

  themes = [
    { value: 'DEFAULT-THEME', label: 'blue' },
    { value: 'LIGHT-THEME', label: 'light' },
    { value: 'NATURE-THEME', label: 'nature' },
    { value: 'BLACK-THEME', label: 'dark' }
  ];

  @Input()
  title: string;

  constructor(private appSettingsService: AppSettingsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {  
    console.log('settings title, ', this.title);
    console.log('settings: ', this.defaultSettings)
    //this.appSettingsService.getSettings()
      //.subscribe(console.log(defaultSettings),
        //() => null,
        //() => {
          //console.log('settings: ', this.settings);
        //});
    console.log('settings, stickyHeader: ', this.settings.stickyHeader);  
  }
```

Even though I've commented out the subscribe code, I'm still getting the following runtime error:

```
vendor.js:76623 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:     StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SettingsContainerComponent -> AppSettingsService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SettingsContainerComponent ->     AppSettingsService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AppSettingsService!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SettingsContainerComponent ->     AppSettingsService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SettingsContainerComponent ->     AppSettingsService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AppSettingsService!
    at     NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get     (vendor.js:69804)
```

The full project can be found at https://github.com/cpeddie/TRACS3.git

Can somebody point me to the correct way of doing this?

Thanks....

Comment: did you provide the service in your module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your service globally available in Angular app either add `providedIn: 'root'` to your service metadata:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppSettingsService {
  ...
}
```

or add this service to `providers` array of your AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [AppSettingsService ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```